# Fail to view data before lookup stage in datastage

Tags: mysql, hive, datastage

I've a process in datastage to lookup value from some table.
Usually I check the connection and the data before the next step (transform, lookup, etc).
But suddenly, one of hive connector is cannot show the data although the connection is similar with the other hive connector.
The one hive connector is refer to test_etl.master_jns_pekerjaan hive table.
When I click the view data button it show warning below

[image]

the data is from mysql that imported to hive and below is the data that succesfully imported to hive

[image]

how I should fix it?

Comment: I suggest to check the data length for the fields - truncation seems something is not big enough.

Comment: Solved, It needs to change the default length for column from 200 to 400 because the some data, its length is more than 200